# Issue in building Superhero IOS Wallet

Tags: aeternity-blockchain

I am trying to build the superhero wallet into IOS.

I was following the readme and did following steps.

cordova prepare ios
Opened xcode with the .xcodeprojec file
Showing this Issues

Value for SWIFT_VERSION cannot be empty.

Any help is appreciated

thanks